# Events - Handler vs direct access? Why?

Tags: c#, events, handler

SAMPLE CODE:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName) 
{ 
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged; 
    if (handler != null) 
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

VS:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName) 
{ 
    if (PropertyChanged!= null) 
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Why is it that I always see people creating assigning PropertyChanged to a "handler" instead of just using it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you do it the simpler way, and a different thread removes the last handler from the event just inside your `if`, you'll get a null reference.  (delegates are immutable)

By making a `handler` temporary, you prevent this, since you only check the field once.

If the event will *never* be unsubscribed to from multiple threads, you don't need the temporary.

Comment: I'm a bad coder then. Did you ever actually see this happen? :) Seriously, I wouldn't like to add another compulsion to my list if it's such scenario never occurs like I think it doesn't :)

Comment: @Nikola It happens, and can happen easily, in multithreaded code.  That being said, it's easy to write code that completely avoids the issue (1st cast), so why not prevent the problem from occurring?

Comment: @Reed, I'm aware this can theoretically happen, I just think that chances are slim to nil to have such horrific code that adds/removes event handlers at a spectacular rate in several threads that would give sufficient probability of threads being switched at just the right moment :) Anyway, there's another nice way to get around that problem: private event EventHandler SomethingHappend = delegate { };

Comment: @Nikola That's reducing efficiency, and not as safe, as you can remove that event handler... I've had this happen, in real production code.  It's also not always the easiest to debug.

Comment: @Nikola: That is a terrible idea for efficiency reasons as Reed says.  My question is; when faced with the choice of writing better, more robust code at almost zero inconvenience, why would you ever chose not to?

Comment: @Nikola: And also: * I just think that chances are slim to nil to have such horrific code that adds/removes event handlers at a spectacular rate in several threads that would give sufficient probability of threads being switched at just the right moment* - You must not write a lot of multithreaded code then.  That's called a race condition and it happens all the time.

Comment: @Reed, thanks. I didn't think this is likely to actually happen in production. I'll be wary of this then. Ed, I don't know if you meant to provide any input. I was asking if this actually happened to someone in production, not what race condition is.

Answer (score 5):

> Did you ever actually see this happen?

Sure, this takes a fraction of second to bomb on my machine after starting it:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        EventHandler anEvent = null;
        var t1 = ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((w) => {
            for (; ; ) {
                anEvent += Test;
                anEvent -= Test;
            }
        });
        var t2 = ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((w) => {
            for (; ; ) {
                if (anEvent != null) anEvent(null, null);
            }
        });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Test(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
}
```

It is a quick crash due to the relentlessly quick looping.  In a real app this takes anywhere between a day and a year to crash.  The odds that you'll catch it while debugging your code are very slim.  If it does happen you'll go, "wtf? Let's try again" and not get it again.